# Strange behavior between debug and release in Gcc5.3.0

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

### Situation

I use GCC 5.3.0 provided by Mingw on Window 7, and gtest to implement and run unit tests.

In my project, I have a hierarchy of computers, which implements the interface `Computer` as below :

```
class Dataset; // Not

// Interface Computer
class Computer {
public:
    // Destructor virtual to enable vmap
    virtual ~Computer() noexcept = default;

    // Pure virtual fonctions
    virtual bool preCompute(Dataset &datas) const = 0;
    virtual void compute(Dataset &datas) const = 0;


};
```

I provide an abstract implementation of this interface as `ChainableComputer`, which implements another interface (`Chainable`) and a default implementation of `precompute`. See below.

```
class ChainableComputer : public Computer, public Chainable {
    public:
         bool preCompute(Dataset &dataset) const  override;
};
```

Those classes are in a namespace, called `core`, and packaged in core.dll

In another dll, i have implementation of `ChainableComputer` in another namespace `domain`.

Some of the implementation are simple, and don't have any thing to do in preCompute, so, they implements compute with the same way :

```
class SomeComputerImpl  : public ChainableComputer{
/// ...
void compute(Dataset &datas) const override final{
       auto result = preCompute(datas);
       if(!result){
          throw;
       }
}
};
```

This code was spreading so i decided to refactor and add a protected method in Computer :

```
class Computer  {
/// ...
protected:
    // Helper function for some implementations of Computer
    void doPrecomputeOrThrow(Dataset &datas) const{
       auto result = preCompute(datas);
       if(!result){
          throw;
       }
    } 
}
```

I don't wan't this behavior to be the default for computer, but it give me the possibility to change implementation of these computer as below :

```
class SomeComputerImpl  : public ChainableComputer{
/// ...
void compute(Dataset &datas) const override final{
       doPrecomputeOrThrow(Dataset &datas);
}
};
```

It compiles and works well in the application and in the unit test... if i compile and run in Release mode.

If I choose Debug, the compiling works, the application work, but the tests don't.

I try to understand what it could happen, but I cannot figure out what could be wrong. I guess it has something to with the linker, and the fact that the interface, an abstract implementation and the concrete implementation are in separates DLL, and that we run this stuff in another executable...

### What i already try

1. Implement a `ChainableComputer` directly in the test => works as expected
2. Plays with `inline` or `__attribute__(always_inline)` on `doPrecomputeOrThrow`=> no effect
3. Implementing `doPrecomputeOrThrow` in namespace (passing Computer * as argument), in core.dll => no effect
4. Implementing `doPrecomputeOrThrow` in namespace (passing Computer * as argument), in domain.dll => works as expected
5. Implementing `doPrecomputeOrThrow` as template in class or in namespace, with `Computer` as template parameter (see below) => works as expected
6. Implementing `doPrecomputeOrThrow` as template in class, with `Dataset` as template parameter (see below) => no effect

   // Template which works, as member of `Computer` (static or not), or
   // in namespace
   template 
   void doPrecomputerOrThrows(AComputer * c, Dataset& datas);

   // Template which doesn't work, as member of `Computer` 
   template 
   void doPrecomputerOrThrows(ADataset& datas);

### The Question

There is someone who have an idea of what happens ?

Comment: Not going through your code, but different behavior in debug and release is almost always a result of undefined behavior. Try running your code through static analyzer, sanitizer or valgrind.

Comment: This question would greatly benefit from a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Good question. I agree with @JasonR. A compilable example will go a long way.

Comment: I have to ask: why GCC under Windows? This would most definitely benefit from a debugger stepping into the actual code. But can you run `gdb` under Windows? Also, as suggested you need an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for us to evaluate.

Comment: I have to ask the obvious question: You recompiled, linked, and installed `core.dll` and `domain.dll` in debug mode before you linked your app to them in debug mode, right?

Comment: I will try to create a MCVE, but it's not easy (it's a part of a really big project)

Comment: @Mark B : Yes, core.dll and domain.dll have been compiled in debug before linking it to my tests executable (in the log, i can see cored.dll and domaind.dll). That's not the problem

Comment: @ Ælex When we started the project, MSVC wasn't really up to date on implementation of last standard of C ++ 14. Mingw/GCC5.3. provided with Msys2 works very well, by the way, and we can use gdb.

Comment: I tried to have a compilable example, but, for now, there is no problem with the minimal case. I will try to add stuff from my really big project to understand what happens (the only thing I can imagine is a wrong memory write which break the v-table of my Computers... But if it is that, it won't be easy to reproduce in a minimal exemple)